# Is it possible to communicate with http requests between web and worker processes on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm building an HTTP -> IRC proxy, it receives messages via an HTTP request and should then connect to an IRC server and post them to a channel (chat room).

This is all fairly straightforward, the one issue I have is that a connection to an IRC server is a persistent socket that should ideally be kept open for a reasonable period of time - unlike HTTP requests where a socket is opened and closed for each request (not always true I know). The implication of this is that a message bound for the same IRC server/room must always be sent via the same process (the one that holds a connection to the IRC server).

So I basically need to receive the HTTP request on my web processes, and then have them figure out which specific worker process has an open connection to the IRC server and route the message to that process.

I would prefer to avoid the complexity of a message queue within the IRC proxy app, as we already have one sitting in front of it that sends it the HTTP requests in the first place.

With that in mind my ideal solution is to have a shared datastore between the web and worker processes, and to have the worker processes maintain a table of all the IRC servers they're connected to. When a web process receives an HTTP request it could then look up the table to figure out if there is already a worker with a connection the the required IRC server and forward the message to that, or if there is no existing connection it could effectively act as a load balancer and pick an appropriate worker to forward the message to so it can establish and hold a connection to the IRC server.

Now to do this it would require my worker processes to be able to start an HTTP server and listen for requests from the web processes. On Heroku I know only web processes are added to the public facing "routing mesh" which is fine, what I would like to know is is it possible to send HTTP requests between a web and worker process internally within Herokus network (outside of the "routing mesh").

I will use a message queue if I must be as I said I'd like to avoid it.

Thanks!